# How to read multiple values at once from plist files using "defaults" in MAC OSX

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, plistbuddy

I have a plist file which contains keys like

```
Area
Name
City
Country
```

As per defaults man page one can read a key from plist like this

```
defaults read plist-file key
```

E.g.

```
defaults read abc.plist Area
```

However I want to read more than one key using defaults.

```
defaults read abc.plist Area City Country
```

The above produces output only of `Area`, not of `City` and `Country`.

**Can anyone please suggest how can I read multiple keys from plist in one go using defaults only?**

Comment: I haven't put this as an answer because you said *"... using only defaults"*, but an intuitive way to do it, to me at least, is with **GNU Parallel**, which would be `parallel -k defaults read abc.plist ::: Area City Country`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
defaults read path/to/your plist
```

Comment: I have edited your answer. Can you please provide the required solution

Comment: defaults read plist-file give the value for all the keys existing in the plist. and you can choose after that what ever key-value you want.

Comment: I dont want to perform any select operation on the output. I juts want the values of the keys i specified in the command. Is there any way to achieve it using defaults command

Answer (score 0):

> **Can anyone please suggest how can I read multiple keys from plist in one go using defaults only?**

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for key in Area City Country; do defaults read abc.plist $key; done
```